# Disable an Outlook add-in for Windows and keep it enabled for Mac OS or vice-versa

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

I have a use case where our product can be installed on windows and/or macOS.
So if our product is not installed on either platform, does outlook add-in manifest provide any option to enable/disable on a specific platform or web ?

Ex:
Supported : Windows,         Unsupported : MacOS, Browsers
Supported : MacOS,           Unsupported : Windows, Browsers
Supported : MacOS, Windows   Unsupported : Browsers

Comment: For browsers, I think there is a manifest tag 'MobileFormFactor' to enable browsers, so if its not provided, may be mobile is not supported ?
I havent deployed and tried this.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this with Office Add-ins.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such property or setting for web add-ins.

But you can use the `Office.context` object to determine at runtime the `platform` where the add-in is running. So, you could do proceed further or just disable any further actions in the add-in (inactivate it).

- macOS (Outlook Desktop):

```
{
  contentLanguage: "en-US"
  diagnostics: {
     host: "Outlook", 
     version: "16.47.314.0",
     platform: "Mac"
  },
  displayLanguage: "en-US",
  host: "Outlook",
  isDialog: false,
  platform: "Mac"
}
```

- macOS (Outlook Web):

```
{
  contentLanguage: "",
  diagnostics: {
    host: "Outlook",
    platform: "OfficeOnline",
    version: "0.0.0.0"
  },
  displayLanguage: "en-US",
  host: "Outlook",
  isDialog: false,
  platform: "OfficeOnline"
}
```